# list 1st folder in zip

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working with python. I want to print first folder without any other files or folders. There are 100 files and 1 folder in the zip.
Using this code list me all files and folders in the zip file

```
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
print zip_ref.namelist()
```

[list only folder in red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/035FV.jpg)
I only want to get list for the first folder without any other files or folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, that looks like invalid Python, indentation error.

Comment: it manage to print, but all files and folder..refer link i just included

Comment: My guess, the anwser is: `zip_ref.namelist()[0]`?